# Finding an object on an infinite line

Tags: algorithms, programming-logic

#### Question:

There is an infinite line. You are standing at a particular point you can either move 1 step forward or 1 step backward. You have to search for an object in that infinite line. Your object can be in any direction. Give an optimal solution

#### My approach:

```
       Go 1 step forward, 2 step back ward 
       Go 2 step forward, 4 step back ward and so on
```

#### Complexity:

Lets say the required object is at point n.

Total number of steps:

```
 3 + 6 + 9 + .... n
 = 3(1 + 2 + 3 ... n)
 = O(n^2)
```

Is there a way to improve the efficiency?

Comment: +1 step, -2 steps, +2 steps = +1 step.. kinda pointless don't you think? What about (-1)^i * 2^i steps instead ?

Comment: Got your point! I can increment it in power of 2. Whats (-1)^i?

Comment: It's an infinite series of the form 1, -1, 1, -1... At the i-th step, the value is (-1)^i.

Comment: @Frank: No, it has to be just (-1)^i * i. The exponential sequence does not cover all elements.

Comment: If you have the coordinates for the objects and the vector for the line then I'm pretty sure you can solve this through simple linear algebra instead of brute forcing it through stepping.

Comment: @JanHudec I only referred to the multiplicative factor that made navigation go left or right, since that's what the OP queried.

Comment: If I reword this in English --I have to search for an object in an unordered doubly linked list where my current pointer is in the middle of the list and the size of the list is infinite. Correct?

Comment: clone yourself and walk in both directions at once, no backtracking required

Comment: This problem is not solvable without some statistical details about where the object might be.  As it stands, the best solution is one that never wastes time revisiting old points, and thus counterintuitively is to go one direction only.  (With a 50% chance of being wrong, and as someone else noted, having essentially no chance of finding it if the object can be anywhere on the line with equal chance.)  In order to be solvable, either the line has to be finite or the position of the object must be more likely to appear on some points than others.

Comment: @FrankShearar: I was responding to the very first comment, not the one explaining `(-1)^i`.

Comment: I think this question would be better on http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe  +1 `fork()` is the best answer from a programming perspective.

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean by 'optimal solution' ?
Make as few steps as possible?
I would **not** increase the distance from the start point by 1 every time, because after some time you nearly always visit a position you already visited and the ratio of new visited points converges to 0. I would use a pattern that guarantees that we always visit a fixed ratio of new points.
E.g
r: right step
l: left step

```
                x
                 r              new: 1   old: 0
               ll               new: 2   old: 1
                rrrr            new: 4   old: 3 
           llllllll             new: 8   old: 7
            rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr    new:16   old:15
```

This way the ratio of already visited positions to new visited positions id always about 1:1.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the complexity?. Looking at the series, total number of steps are: 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 .... n, where n is the point where the required element is located. Whats the big-oh complexity?

Answer (score 5):

An exponential growth strategy runs O(n) time, average and worst case. This is optimal if you disregard constant factors. If you want to optimize the constant factor as well, you need to make some assumption about the probability distribution.

For example if you use a doubling strategy, the maximal cost is 7*n

```
dist = 1
loop
    MoveTo(dist)
    MoveTo(-dist)
    dist = dist * 2
```

Comment: Correct, but with one proviso. The question does not say whether integral variable is available and on Turing Machines it usually isn't.

Comment: Can you explain how the run time of exponential growth is O(n)?

Comment: This expands nice and fast. But how does bracketing the object help when other steps are empty?  How do you even know when you've bracketed it?  If there is a way I don't see it in the question.  Isn't that an assumption?

Comment: @CandiedOrange My assumption is that the walker will know when they find the object.

Comment: @CodesInChaos is it correct then that your `moveto()` moves one step at a time until it reaches dist?

Comment: @CodesInChaos then this still ends up covering ground that has already been explored doesn't it?

Comment: @CandiedOrange It moves to the given position, one step at a time. It covers ground several times. But since the earlier iterations are exponentially smaller than the last one, their contribution is only a constant factor to the total distance (related to the convergence of the geometric series). There might be tweaks of the strategy that reduce the constant factor, I only aimed for O(n).

Comment: @CodesInChaos Your statement above that the maximal cost is 7 * n is false.  For example, suppose that n = -4.1.  Your algorithm will walk to these points in succession: 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 4, -4, 8, -4.1.  The total length of this path is 1+2+3+4+6+8+12+12.1 = 48.1, which is more than 7 * 4.

Comment: @CodesInChaos If you work out the math, you can see that the maximum cost to reach a point with distance n from the origin is actually 13 n - 4. This happens when (as in my example above) the point is just beyond a power of 2, and is on the negative side of the line.  Of course, this is still O(n). :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- Each step costs time
- There is no predicting where this object is on the infinite "line" of steps
- That you can't fork or clone your self
- That you only gain more information once you're on the object (no hints as you go)

Then pick a direction at random and just start walking.  No expensive backtracking. Sure it might be one step behind you but that's just the end of infinity right there.

O(n)

Comment: This algorithm has a chance of never terminating so it's not O(anything). The exponential reversing solution is O(n) - why is this method better?

Comment: Any algorithm searching for an object on an infinite line has a chance of never terminating.  Exponential is exponentially expensive if each step costs time. Even if it isn't all you're doing is scrambling infinity before you check each step 1 at a time.  If there were information to gain from misses exponential would be a good start to a binary search.  We weren't offered any hints as we go.  A miss is just a miss.

Comment: I think you aren't taking the time to think through this problem or understand the exponential algorithm. The exponential algorithm _does_ terminate always, and its running time is proportional to the magnitude of the position of the object.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret I think you're making assumptions about the problem that it never states.  Chief among them is random access.  As for stopping,  my sin is the same as the exponential.  I miss the object behind me. Exponential misses the object when it's not on the powers of 2.  Even if you cover everything in both directions you miss the object that's halfway to infinity because the sun burned out.

Comment: Exponential doesn't only hit powers of two. It hits everything between and it alternates directions. As I said, slow down and take more time to understand what you're commenting on.

Comment: You see [this](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/210541/131624) hitting everything between 2 and 4?  You're not asking me to slow down. You're asking me to make assumptions.  And even if I make that one you still don't ever have a higher chance of finding the object this way then my way.  Do `i` checks on a line `n` long you have `i/n` chance of finding it regardless of the steps you choose to check.  So long as `n>i` there is no guarantee of stopping either way.

Comment: Yes it hits everything in between because that's the only reasonable definition of `MoveTo`.

Comment: Oh, ok. So everything works because it's supposed to work.  Reality need not apply.

Comment: For god's sake. The OP even states you can only go one position forward or backward in a step.

Comment: For god's sake how is this more 'efficient'? You're walking over already checked steps for no reason other than you can't stand the idea of missing something close to you even though it's more likely to be far from you. It's an infinite line remember?

Comment: For one thing, the "efficient" algorithm always terminates whereas yours doesn't. For another thing, the "efficient" algorithm is O(n) which is optimal up to a constant. I think those properties are enough to call it efficient.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret so long as `n>i` nothing can guarantee to terminate.   You're randomly obsessing on the area where you started when you've been given no reason to.  Before the first move there is an equal chance of finding the object to the left and to the right.  It's just as efficient to go either way. As soon as you make that first move there is zero chance of finding it by moving back one step.  That move is wasteful.  Do that even once and you're forever behind the "just start walking" approach.

Comment: So what's your better, less wasteful idea? An algorithm that doesn't terminate on half of all inputs? That sounds quite wasteful to me.

Comment: Half? You just keep forgetting this is infinite.  We'll all be dead before any of these gets to half.  I'm just trying to get lucky before we die.  The difference is, every move I'm playing a fresh lottery ticket while the others are picking over ones that have already been scratched off.

Answer (score -1):

On an infinite line you will never find the object.  Infinity is a weird thing. i.e. pick a point on a finite line, as the length of the line approaches infinity the probability that the point you picked is the object approaches zero.

Some things that might make this problem meaningful

1. The line is finite (some number N)
2. The object can only be at discrete points.

I would image that in these cases the optimal (fewest number of steps) solution would be to walk in one direction until you find the object or reach the end.  If you reach the end you would turn around.

Comment: the object has to be a finite distance from your start position the line itself can still be infinite though

Comment: -1: Turing machines _always_ feature (countable) infinite tape. Anything that lies on such tape lies in _finite_ distance, because every distance between concrete elements on an infinite tape is finite. The infinite tape is important, because on a finite tape you can run to one end, than to the other, but on an infinite one you can't, because you'll never reach the end.

Comment: 1: Having a finite line would not matter if we consider the reals. [0, 1] is just as impossible to enumerate as (-inf, +inf). 2: Really all you need is a line that is a subset of a countable set (for example, the rationals).